org mode radio table from manual doesn't work
I took the radio table example from the manual. Put it in an org file and pressed C-c C-c inside the table.
I get the message C-c C-c can do nothing useful here
What am I doing wrong?
Example:
% BEGIN RECEIVE ORGTBL salesfigures
% END RECEIVE ORGTBL salesfigures
\begin{comment}
#+ORGTBL: SEND salesfigures orgtbl-to-latex
| Month | Days | Nr sold | per day |
|-------+------+---------+---------|
| Jan   |   23 |      55 |     2.4 |
| Feb   |   21 |      16 |     0.8 |
| March |   22 |     278 |    12.6 |
#+TBLFM: $4=$3/$2;%.1f
% $ (optional extra dollar to keep Font Lock happy, see footnote)
\end{comment}



There is also my own recommended code from a decade ago:
orig_table = """
#+ORGTBL: SEND marks orgtbl-to-generic :lfmt " \"%s\": [%s,%s,%s,%s,%s]," :llfmt " \"%s\": [%s,%s,%s,%s,%s]"
| abe       | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 10 |
| beth      | 9 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 24 |
| catherine | 8 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 26 |
#+TBLFM: $6=$2+$3+$4+$5
"""

stud_db = {
# Dont hand-edit
# BEGIN RECEIVE ORGTBL marks
# END RECEIVE ORGTBL marks 


Now when I try it as is it works. If I delete the first line and make the #+ORGTBL:... the first line, emacs crashes!   [Hour-glass until I press C-g]

BTW, your recommended code (both the "old" and the "new")  works fine for me.

With the line orig_table = """ removed it works?@NickD? org veersion?. Here it is 9.8-pre

No, it does not: the problem is that you need to have the Org table inside a comment, so that the language processor can't see it (it's not legal LaTeX, or Python, or C ...). In LaTeX, the \begin{comment} ... \end{comment} achieves that; in Python, the triple-quoted string achieves that. You don't have to have the orig_table =  part, but you do need the triple-quotes.

Actually, it works without the triple quotes for me in the sense that C-c C-c on the table does the radio-table thing and fills out the python structure. But if you C-c C-c somewhere else, that tries to run the python program and that chokes with a syntax error. Wait: I'm on Org mode 9.5.4 (I switched to check something and forgot to switch back) - I'll switch back to something modern and redo the testing. I'll let you know.

@NickD "chokes" means error mesg or hang?

I'm back in modern times: Org mode version 9.8-pre (release_9.7.3-28-gdc2f27). I open the .py file (without the orig_table === line), enable orgtbl mode and press C-c C-c on the #+ORGTBL line: it does the radio-table thing and fills out the python structure stud_db as it should. If I press C-c C-c outside of the table, it says: python-shell-get-process-or-error: Start a Python process first with M-x run-python or ‘C-c C-p’, I then start a Python process with M-x run-python and do C-c C-c again (outside the table): it chokes with an error message in the *Python* buffer...

... which says: In [1]:    File /tmp/foo.py:15     | abe       | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 10 |     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax  which is not surprising. I use ipython  as my python-shell-interpreter, which accounts for why the above might look different than what you would expect, but I can't see why that should make a difference.

BTW, how do we move this whole discussion to chat?

Let's move this discussion to chat.

You are supposed to include this snippet in a *TeX* file (not an Org mode file), enable orgtbl mode in that file, and then press C-c C-c on the #+ORGTBL line (or in the table). That will fill in the BEGIN/END RECEIVE block with the LaTeX version of the table. That's what you specified in the SEND line: orgtbl-to-latex will do that conversion.
If you want to, you can do it with an Org mode file: you just need to enable orgtbl mode. But the result is not particularly useful in that case. But you can use a different translator for special cases: do C-h f orgtbl-to- TAB to find out what's available.

Tnx Nick. I had copy-pasted my own code from 11 years ago wrong. Nevertheless, it does hang: whether its emacs or some inferior python process I am not sure (top shows 99% emacs). I've added the code to my question. As is it works. But if I delete the first line and make the #+ORGTBL: ... the first line in the file it crashes. It only crashes if the ORGTBL is the 1st line of the file; doesnt depend on Python being syntactically right/wrong. Seems like a bug. Can you check?
